# How does this dialer work?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

When I press certain numbers on the dialer of my phone, names are brought up which don't make any sense. I've used T9 dialer, but I can't understand this. For example le, typing 77 brings up names starting with Ap, and Dr. Typing 34 brings up names starting with He, and Ad. I just wanted to know if there's any reason for this.

The OS is Jelly Bean 4.1.1

EDIT: As some of the answers point out that it may be a part of a number of one of the contacts. I've checked it before, it only happens after I type three numbers. And if it is a part of a number, that string is highlighted.

But when I type just two numbers, the names come up with their first two letters highlighted.

Comment: Isn't it possible those are just number sequences found in the telephone number of the listed people? The list refines as the numbers are input.

Answer (score 3):

The dialer will look for things that match the T9 query as well as search your contacts that have the string of numbers associated with their phone number.

For example if you have contact John Smith with phone number 123-456-7890 and you dialed "78" he would show up because that string matches part of his phone number. If you dialed dialed "56" he would also show up because that matches his name "Jo" as well as part of his phone number "56".

I hope that helps!